# How to call ssh from script(csh/tcsh)?

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, command-line, csh

I have different servers with different IPs with I can ssh in any servers and get my database intact (I don't know how, I am just an user). 
I have written one script to move from one server to other server using ssh in the same directory where I was in first server.

Here you can see final command that if I type will work:

```
ssh -X usr@192.168.1.xyz -t 'cd /home/usr/regression && exec /bin/csh'
```

Now here a part of small script:

```
set path = $PWD  
set user = $1  

set cmd = "ssh -X $user@192.168.$ip3.$ip4 -t 'cd $path && exec $SHELL'"
echo $cmd;
$cmd;
```

Since It is csh/tcsh script I just want to run

> $cmd

command but it give this message:

> ssh: Command not found.

While If I copy,paste and run the final command that I am getting with:

```
echo "$cmd"
```

Like :

> ssh -X usr@192.168.1.xyz -t 'cd /home/usr/regression && exec /bin/csh'

Then It works fine.

Comment: seems like it should work. Did you try it with just a bare `$cmd` (no trailing `;`) ? But, how could it work with `192.16.1.xyz` ;-? Good luck.

Comment: @shellter I am not using ; in last command "$cmd" ......xyz is just for example it can by any number 210... :-) Wumpus Q. Wumbley solved this problem it is path variable.

Comment: Yes here I saw I have typed ; with $cmd. But I am not using it as is in my script. Since I have echo statement before this $cmd in my script......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `path` variable in csh is a magic array tied to the `PATH` environment variable. When you changed it, you lost your original `PATH`. Not just ssh, but all external commands will fail after that because none of them can be found, unless they are in `$PWD` which is your new `PATH`.

Call your `path` variable something else.

Comment: Thanks @Wumpus Q. Wumbley, I changed my variable name now I am able to login using ssh. Still one issue is there It ask for password but after that says " cd /my_path/ " : Command not found ......